# Android : How to take a screenshot in android programming and then save to external storage?

Tags: android, screenshot

I am creating an app in android in which the user creates a drawing by touching the screen and then
save it to storage.

My problem is that sometimes the directory does not created , sometimes the image saves but there are a lot of images saved in directory with black images.

The main file saving operation occurs in getDrawnMessage() method.

Here is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawWrite extends View {
float TouchXD = 0, TouchYD = 0, TouchXU = 0, TouchYU = 0, TouchXM = 0,
        TouchYM = 0; // Define touch co-ordinates
float x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0; // Define drawing path co-ordinates
float stroke = 2; // Define the message structure width
int i=0;
boolean Move = false, moveD = false, moveU = false; // Define whether the
                                                    // touch has occurred or
                                                    // not
boolean exp = false;
Paint paint = new Paint(); // Paint object
Path mPath = new Path(); // Define the drawing message path
Context context;

public DrawWrite(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    invalidate();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    if (DrawWriteActivity.clearScreen){
        mPath.reset();
        DrawWriteActivity.clearScreen = false;
    }
    cleanButton(canvas);
    try {
        getDrawnMessage(canvas);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(DrawWriteActivity.colorProvider));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(DrawWriteActivity.strokeProvider);
    if (moveD == true) {
        x1 = TouchXD;
        y1 = TouchYD;
        moveD = false; 
    } else if (Move == true) {
        x2 = TouchXD;
        y2 = TouchYD;
        mPath.moveTo(x1, y1);
        mPath.lineTo(x2, y2);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        TouchXD = (float) event.getX();
        TouchYD = (float) event.getY();
        moveD = true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        TouchXU = (float) event.getX();
        TouchYU = (float) event.getY();
        moveU = true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        TouchXD = (float) event.getX();
        TouchYD = (float) event.getY();
        Move = true;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void getDrawnMessage(Canvas canvas) throws FileNotFoundException{
    if(exp){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File imgDir = new File(root+"/ChitBak/");
        String imgName;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        imgDir.mkdirs();
        imgName = "img"+i+".jpg";
        i++;
        File file = new File(imgDir,imgName);
        if(file.exists()) file.delete();
        FileOutputStream outImg = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outImg);  
        exp = false;
        Intent in = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        context.startActivity(in);
    }
}

private void cleanButton(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(getWidth() - 100, getHeight() - 70,
            getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20), 10, 10, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    paint.setTextSize(27);
    paint.setTextSkewX((float) 0.2);
    canvas.drawText("Save", getWidth() - 92, getHeight() - 35, paint);
}

private void isResetRequested() {
    if (TouchXD >= (getWidth() - 100) && TouchYD >= getHeight() - 70
            && TouchXD <= (getWidth() - 20) && TouchYD <= getHeight() - 20){
        exp = true;
    }
}
}
```

Please help me friends because i don't know how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

If you want anything in code then tell me i will provide it.

Comment: hi! Your bitmap in getDrawnMessage is always empty. I mean the size is correct, but you dont use your canvas, aou passing in this method!

Answer (score 0):

I think your capture method is wrong.

**Saving the View as a Bitmap**

Here is a code I'm using to dump an entire view into a `Bitmap` (this will not save the notification bar nor the navigation bar):

```
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = ApplicationHelper.resources().getDisplayMetrics();
    if (displayMetrics == null) {
        LogHelper.warning("DisplayMetrics was NULL");
        return null;
    }

    view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();

    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
```

Remember that you can use `android.R.id.content` to get your entire application's screen space, as a `View`.

**Saving to external storage**

With `file.mkdirs()` your code should work.